Constantly receiving the Kernal : XFS file system (Or) Disk I/O write back errors after executing the few application testcases
**Prod Error Logs Received:
**
XFS (dm-3): metadata I/O error in "xfs_buf_ioend+0x2af/0x620
XFS (dm-3): metadata I/O error in "xfs_buf_ioend+0x2af/0x620 [xfs]" at daddr 0x6c8c50 len 8 error 28
XFS (dm-3): Failing async write on buffer block 0x6c8c50.
XFS: Failing async write: 4129 callbacks suppressed
kernel: dm-8: writeback error on inode 136, offset 344064, sector 18976
Kernal: XFS (dm-12): Failing async write on buffer block 0x31fe560. Retrying async write.
XFS (dm-12): metadata I/O error in "xfs_buf_ioend+0x2af/0x620
We have taken 2TiB disk and n2-standard-128 machine type. Even after the testcases execution we have the enough disk space, memory and CPU. Any CRON jobs scheduled are not executing after the XFS file system IO Error. And the application URL is getting down. We increased the application mount point size to 1TiB and mostly it uses 2% from it. Not exactly sure, why we are getting this IO error. Not able to perform any activity after this Error as we are seeing the VM slowness.
